# Can't set default value to ion-select ionic v4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I can't set default a value to ion-select ionic v4.

I have a simple `<ion-select></ion-select>` tag with only 2 options.

I'm binding with `[(ngModel)]` and I want to pre-select one of those two options when value is empty, such as  `"Employee"` default selection.

Here's a extract of `ion-select` in  `user.component.html`

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="user.type" id="type" name="type">
    <ion-option value="employee">Employee</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="vendor">Vendor</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

I tried setting in `ngOnInit()` like this:

```
if(user.type == undefined  || user.type == "") user.type = "employee";
```

But I have no success so far. Here's how select turns out:
[image]

Why is it not understanding the instruction I gave before?

Answer (score 0):

The ion-select has a Value tag, so just go ahead and set that:

```
<ion-select value="employee" [(ngModel)]="user.type" id="type" name="type">
    <ion-option value="employee">Employee</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="vendor">Vendor</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Also beware of caps, since you are setting the user type as "Employee" and not "employee" (which is used in the item-option)